# Rotation/Orientation from two vectors

Tags: math, 3d, unity-game-engine, trigonometry

I'm working on a small Unity3D project and I need to import some data from another tool. That tool gives me the object orientation through two vectors, and I need to port that to Unity.

As an example, I have these two vectors;

```
x = Vector( 0.707, 0.707, 0)
y = Vector(-0.707, 0.707, 0)
```

With only this information, I need to understand that my object needs to rotate 45 degrees on the Z axis. The two vectors represent the up and right vectors of my object, not a starting point nor a destination.

**EDIT**

Ok, now I'm able to do single-axis rotation! Yeah! Provided this function;

```
function RotationMaster (vx : Vector3, vy : Vector3) {
    var vz = Vector3.Cross(vx, vy);

    var x = Mathf.Atan2(-vz.y, vz.z) * Mathf.Rad2Deg;
    var y = Mathf.Atan2( vx.z, vx.x) * Mathf.Rad2Deg;
    var z = Mathf.Atan2(-vx.y, vx.x) * Mathf.Rad2Deg;

    Debug.Log("x : " + x + "; y : " + y + "; z : " + z);

    transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(x,y,z);
}
```

I can now pass simple rotation like that:

```
RotationMaster(Vector3(1,0,0), Vector3(0,0.707,0.707));
RotationMaster(Vector3(1,0,0), Vector3(0,-1,0));
```

And as long as I'm not playing with multiple axis, it will work. But as soon as I try a more complexe rotation, it fails... As an example;

```
RotationMaster(Vector3(-0.5,-0.5,0.707), Vector3(-0.707,0.707,0));
```

This is wrong... :-(

Any clue?

Comment: Can you please ask your colleague (or your Stack Overflow's Alter Ego :) to delete her/his question [Convert the Up and Right vectors into Euler or Quaternion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14242481/convert-the-up-and-right-vectors-into-euler-or-quaternion) just to avoid duplicates? If this is just a pure coincidence that 2 people ask the same question with the same sample values within 2 hours then Sorry :)

Comment: Maybe I'm misreading something but isn't this just the first 2 rows of a rotation matrix around the 'Z' axis.  Should be a simple multiplication.

Comment: @Jerdak sounds like a good idea. But then Christian needs to rely on fixed z coordinates.

Comment: Do you need this port as one time fire and forget solution or for permanent imports? What is the 3D format called? Any chance to use Blender, Maya, ... to convert it to FBX or others?

Comment: Theoretically, we do not need z. As we are dealing with up and right vectors, we can easily determine the z vector. But as I have no background in 3D, I'm stuck and can't progress.

Comment: See question for edits...

Comment: @Jerdak I'm not that comfortable with rotation matrix. Could you explain a bit more please?

Comment: @christianblais Kay is right, my comment fixes 'z' coordinates.  The problem is a lack of constraints, you need to generate some sort of 3rd axis.  [Take a look at this page for one solution](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/20097/how-to-calculate-a-3x3-rotation-matrix-from-2-direction-vectors).

Comment: The format is smgXML, from Composer. And it would be for permanent imports.

Comment: It seems to me you don't actually need to covert via Euler angles at all. Just convert directly to quats. That was what you hinted at in the beginning. Direct matrix to quat conversion is also very easy to find in literature

Comment: Why don't you use the [Quaternion.FromToRotation function](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/Quaternion.FromToRotation.html) instead? I think it does what you're trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Quaternion.SetLookRotation
```

was (with few tweaks...) what I was looking for! Thanks to all for your help!

Answer (score 3):

Take a cross product between x and y for full matrix and convert that to space Euler or Tait–Bryan rotations (the conversion needs the 3rd axis to be accurate). This is a fairly well understood conversion, and if you read the conversion routine you realize that it first starts of with a plane solution so you can omit many of the other parts if you need to.

A good general example on how to do this general conversion can be found in Graphics Gems IV, you can find [C sources here](http://tog.acm.org/resources/GraphicsGems/gemsiv/euler_angle/). Or adapted python sources and other goodies [here](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/code/transformations.py.html).

Addendum: To do direct matrix to quaternion translation is described by the same author in Graphics Gems II which can be found [here](http://fs1.bib.tiera.ru/content/ShiZ/math/other/Graphics_Gems_2,ed_J.Arvo.pdf).